# SQL Power function incorrect for high numbers

Tags: sql-server, function

If I try to execute this query:

```
SELECT POWER(CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,0), 64), 10)
```

I receive:

```
1152921504606847000
```

That isn't correct. The correct result is:

```
1152921504606846976
```

How can I receive the correct result?

Comment: [`POWER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx) is defined on floats (or values that can be converted to float), not on decimal - so you have to accept that it's going to do the math with floats, not decimals.

Answer (score 2):

```
select cast(power(convert(float(30), 64), 10) as bigint)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the precision of the computing. You can have very big numbers, but the precision will be off, because you only have a fixed amount of bits to store your values...

[This is a good explanation of the situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199371/sql-server-precision-crazyness)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the correct result, you can calculate it manually.

ie

```
declare @res bigint, @i int
select @res = 64, @i = 1

while @i<10
begin
    select @res = @res * 64, @i=@i+1    
end
select @res
```