# Incorrect conversion from Float to Decimal

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is relatively simple but would like to know the root cause

Sql query to convert Float to Decimal gives incorrect results.

Example:

```
Select CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL(25,8), CONVERT(FLOAT,338193293.16))AS VARCHAR(255))
```

Expected result: `338193293.16000000`

Actual Result: `338193293.16000003`

Where did the extra `3`come from?

Comment: This is a normal behavior. Float tends to give some floating errors. Sounds as bad as it is. Just use decimal, this won't give you such errors.

Comment: might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199371/sql-server-precision-crazyness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of digits are too much - no matter that after decimal point they are only 2. Use shorter number e.g. 38193293.16 or use FLOAT(24). For normal FLOAT there is "Precision = 7 digits".

Comment: The extra digits "003" come from approximation after floating point conversion.

Comment: That was my question, appreciate your help